# login with spring and angular

Tags: angular, spring, oauth-2.0

Goodmorning everyone.
I wrote the following code (frontend angular 2+) and backend in spring. My problem is that when I go to login, I get the following error
{_body: "{" error ":" unauthorized "," error_description ":" There ... ry adding an appropriate authentication filter. "}", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, ... }

and I can not solve the problem. I tried in various ways but unfortunately I can not come out.

Thank you all for your help

link code
https://github.com/rox-ale/angular-login

Answer (score 0):

I think your login url has been filtered by spring security, try this config in your `WebSecurityConfig`

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web.ignoring()
      .antMatchers("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/oauth/token");
}
```